# Buttons not responding in IE 11 after partial postback

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, internet-explorer-11

Submit button stops working after partial post-back in IE11 when used with UpdatePanel(.Net). It's clickable, but it doesn't work.If clicked somewhere on page it starts to work normally.I have few pages in my project with this type of UpdatePanel's, all those pages are not working in IE11.

In UpdatePanel ContentTemplate is used for each drop down.
Buttons used were asp:linkbuttons and normal anchor buttons.

Tried with so many options like keeping meta tag in master page and wrote some javscript to trigger after the selected index changed, but no use... :(
Please help me.

Comment: ...but they are working in other browsers?

Comment: Yes it is working in other browsers @Alexander

Comment: Have you checked for console errors?

Comment: Ya checked for them but no console errors @  Jonathon Cowley-Thom